# how to display mobile website in webbrowser control in windows phone

Tags: windows-phone

this is piece of code i have written to display a mobile website in web browser control in windows phone but nothing happens browser is blank

`webbro.Navigate(new Uri("http://m.bajajfinservlending.in/"), null, "User-Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0,MSIE 10.0; Windows Phone OS 7.0,Windows Phone 8.0; Trident/3.1,Trident/6.0; IEMobile/7.0,IEMobile/10.0; ARM; Touch; NOKIA; Lumia 520)");`

Answer (score 0):

This is enough. Mobile version of the website will be loaded.

```
webbro.Navigate(new Uri("http://m.bajajfinservlending.in/", UriKind.Absolute));
```

To Know, what mistake you have done, copy the url and paste it into desktop browser. The same blank response you will receive as you had in the windows phone web browser. So, the problem is not in the app. It's in your url

Comment: and this url will not run in desktop as we have not allowed it to run on desktop browser.

Comment: please go through the link i am providing [link]http://blog.razorstudio.de/en/2010/12/20/how-to-set-the-webbrowser-controll-to-show-mobile-pages/  I hope this will clear you what i am trying to ask, i solved my problem with the help of this article.

Answer (score 0):

I think my headerstring is incorrect now it is working fine :
'this.webbro.Navigate(new Uri("http://m.bajajfinservlending.in/"),null,User-Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows Phone OS 7.0; Trident/3.1; IEMobile/7.0; HTC; T8788);'